Segmentation fault when using user input but not hardcoded input (C++)
so i was given a Binary Search Tree implementation using C for our data structure class. i wanted to create a BST implementation using C++ to better my understanding of the data structure and C++ since we were slowly moving towards using C++.
it worked just fine when the inserted elements were hardcoded but when i tried to use user inputs i started getting segmentation fault
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Node
{
    public:
        int data;
        Node *left, *right;
        //init
        Node()
        {
            data = 0;
            left = NULL;
            right = NULL;
        }
        Node(int key)
        {
            data = key;
            left = NULL;
            right = NULL;
        }
        //utility
        Node* push(int key)
        {
            Node* newNode;

            if (this==NULL)
            {
                newNode = new Node(key);
                return newNode;
            }
            
            if (key <= this->data)
            {
                this->left = this->left->push(key);
            } else if (key > this->data)
            {
                this->right = this->right->push(key);
            }
            return newNode;
        }
        
        Node* find(int key)
        {
            Node* temp = this;
            while (temp!=NULL)
            {
                if (key<temp->data)
                {
                    if (temp->left==NULL) { return new Node; }
                    temp = temp->left;
                } else if (key>temp->data)
                {
                    if (temp->right==NULL) { return new Node; }
                    temp = temp->right;
                } else
                {
                    return temp;
                }

            }
            return temp;
        }

        Node* find_min()
        {
            Node* temp = this;
            while (temp && temp->left != NULL) { temp = temp->left; }

            return temp;
        }
        
        int find_sum(int key)
        {
            Node* temp = this;
            int sum=0;

            while (temp!=NULL)
            {
                if (key < temp->data)
                {
                    if (temp->left==NULL) {return 0;}
                    sum += temp->data;
                    temp = temp->left;
                } else if (key > temp->data)
                {
                    if (temp->right==NULL) {return 0;}
                    sum += temp->data;
                    temp = temp->right;
                } else {
                    cout << sum<< endl;
                    sum += temp->data;
                    return sum;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }

        void inorder()
        {
            if (this==NULL) return;
            this->left->inorder();
            cout << this->data << " ";
            this->right->inorder();
        }

        void postorder()
        {
            if (this==NULL) return;
            this->left->postorder();
            this->right->postorder();
            cout << this->data << " ";
        }

        void preorder()
        {
            if (this==NULL) return;
            this->left->preorder();
            cout << this->data << " ";
            this->right->preorder();
        }


};

class BST
{
    private:
        Node *root; 
    public:
        //init
        BST()
        {
            root = NULL;
        }
        //functions
        bool empty()
        {
            return (root==NULL);    
        }
        
        void insert(int key)
        {
            root = root->push(key);
        }

        bool find(int key)
        {
            Node *temp = this->root->find(key);
            if (temp==NULL)
            {
                return false;
            } else if (temp->data==key)
            {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        int find_sum(int key)
        {
            int sum = this->root->find_sum(key);
            if (sum==0) 
            {
                return 0;
            } else 
            { 
                return sum;
            }
            return 0;
        }
        void inorder()
        {
            root->inorder();
            cout << endl;
        }

        void postorder()
        {
            root->postorder();
            cout << endl;
        }

        void preorder()
        {
            root->preorder();
            cout << endl;
        }

        void test()
        {
            cout << this->root->data << " " << this->root->right->data << endl;
        }
};


int main()
{
    BST myTree;
    int input;

    //worked fine
    myTree.insert(1);
    myTree.insert(5);
    myTree.insert(2);
    myTree.insert(9);
    myTree.insert(7);
    //segfault
    cin >> input;
    myTree.insert(input);
    myTree.inorder();

    
    return 0;
}


element inserted like this also experienced segmentation fault
input = 11;
myTree.insert(input);

when i tried debugging using gdb it pointed the segfault to the traversal and find functions. when they aren't called the debugger says it exited normally.
tl;dr: implemented BST using class in C++. segmentation fault occoured when inserting element using user input but worked fine with hard coded input. debugger doesn't detect segfault unless traversal/find functions are called.

Don't just use the debugger to catch the crash, instead step through the code line by line to see what happens. I also suggest you use pencil and paper to draw out the operations you do on the tree. Use labeled boxes for the nodes, and arrows for links and pointers. Erase and redraw arrows when you change the link/pointer in the code. Does the drawing make sense?

As a hint, what happens with root->push(key) if root is a null pointer? Like it is when you default.construct the BST object. Just because something seems to "work fine", doesn't mean your code doesn't have undefined behavior.

Your debugger will tell you where exactly the crash happens. Look at the stack trace. This will provide you with information that possibly will help you to find the bug, maybe a null pointer dereferencement or an uninitialized variable.

As an addendum to my previous comment, a check like if (this==NULL) is just wrong. Such a null-pointer check should happen in the calling function, not when you're already have undefined behavior and it's too late. Also please note that NULL is a backward compatibility macro from C. In C++ you should use nullptr. And the push function continue the chain of ignoring null pointers and adding more UB.

Oh I just found an even worse problem: If the node is not a null pointer, you will return newNode. When newNode is not initialized. That means it will have an indeterminate value. And in C++, using indeterminate values in any way also leads to undefined behavior.
